# How to combine Array / Object reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have following hierarchy for my app:

- tabs
- - filter
- - tableData

Now tabs is an array. It contains objects - also the filter object.

Example:

```
[{type:1, filter:{sortBy:publisDate,asc}, order:0, name: 'fun tab'}];
```

Now my ideal reducer setup would be:

I have a tab reducer controlling active tab, order, name etc.

I have then a filter tab controlling filter updates.

Best case I do not have to worry about "activeTab" etc - but the reducer handles the logic. So when I update the filter it is reflected correctly in the array of tabs.

I could put all of this in one reducer but it is a lot and will end in mess.

What is a good strategy to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you want to do with this tabs/filters, but if everything will be related in the same screen i don't see bad to do everything in one reducer. for instance, you could have something like this:

TabsReducer

```
{
  activeTab: 'products',
  filter: {
    term : 'sarasa',
    order: 0,
    sortBy: 'name asc',
  }
}
```

Then, in your reducer if you want to update your filter or something, you can do

```
if (type === 'CHANGE_FILTER_TERM') {
  return {
    ...state,
    filter: {
      ...state.filter,
      term: payload.term
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Yes. It would work. The problem is, that the tabs get more complex and will definitely be bigger as they are right now. The filter reducer atm alone has close to 200 lines. So I wanted to split it so it stays maintainable.